# Will VSTO Work With Microsoft Office for Mac 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

With .NET coming to the Mac, I see no reason why support for VSTO (and therefore the ability to write cross platform office ad-ins) couldn't come with it.

Have there been any announcements to this effect either way? I'm almost certain that they'll support their office web app platform, but I'm a .NET guy, and I'm wondering if there's a new market coming my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Because .Net is not the only thing required for VSTO add-ins. Office add-ins are based on the COM technology which doesn't exist on the Mac.